# Can't add values from combobox to database

Tags: c#

I add values in property in combobox at Collection. Like this.

[image: Add values in combobox]

I want when select 1 items and click button save. I will save into database.

Button `Save` is:

```
CameraDTO obj = new CameraDTO();
obj.DefaultCam = Convert.ToInt16(cbxDefaultCam.Items.ToString());
CameraBUS.CameraInsert(obj);
```

In `CameraBUS.CameraInsert` is:

```
    public void Camera_Insert(CameraDTO data)
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Camera_Insert", GetConnection()))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DefaultCam", data.DefaultCam));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Following is the error am getting while executing.

[image]

Comment: instead `cbxDefaultCam.Items.ToString()` try this `cbxDefaultCam.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cbxDefaultCam.Items` returns a collection of `ComboBoxItem`. it cannot be converted to string using `.ToString()` or even `Convert.To..()` instead for this you can use any of the following based on your use.

- `cbxDefaultCam.SelectedItem.Text`  <-- which gives the bounded text field
- `cbxDefaultCam.SelectedValue`  <-- which gives the bounded value field

Comment: SelectedItem not have property .Text. But .ToString() work for me. Like this
`obj.DefaultCam = Convert.ToInt16(cbxDefaultCam.SelectedItem.ToString());`. Thank you!